# Using PHP insert current date time in sql server via sqlsrv drivers

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, datetime, sqlsrv

Till now I have tried

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table-name(col-name) values (cureent_timestamp)";
```

and have set the column data type as **`datetime`** , I get some values but no date or time.

Comment: It will give you current time-stamp in a string format.

Comment: Use **NOW()** MySQL function for this.

Comment: Is that the exact Insert statement you are using because it looks totally wrong. I trust by db-name you mean the table name.

Comment: What type of values are you getting and what do you actually want to get I mean in what format. Can you also what exact query you are using

Comment: Yea Antony that's a typo it actually is table-name..sry for that!

Comment: nitigyan some Binary data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it using `datetime` data type for the column-

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');      //Don't forget this..I had used this..just didn't mention it in the post

$datetime_variable = new DateTime();
$datetime_formatted = date_format($datetime_variable, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "UPDATE table-name SET col-name = '$time_formatted' WHERE ---";
$sql = sqlsrv_query($connection,$sql);
```

However I am not able to get the perfect datetime. I am getting the next day's date. I am on it! Thanks all for the help!
Solved that as well, just need a minor adjustment to the timezone of the computer.

Comment: So you had to expand the column size? This is basically the same as my answer but your use a DateTime object instead.

Comment: No I didn't expand col size. I used datetime, for your question I tried using timestamp but I showed error, and then when I switched back to datetime..it shows proper datetime like I said! Now I need to figure out why is showing me date as one day ahead.

Answer (score 6):

[`GETDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) should give you the current date:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO db-name(col-name) VALUES (GETDATE())";
```

Comment: What data type should I use?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP (your code isn't very clear where you are getting `cureent_timestamp` from which is spelt wrong by the way). You may want to do this,

```
$current_timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "INSERT INTO db-name(col-name) values ('{$current_timestamp}')";
```

But using MySQL functions that other people have answered are probably better in your case, just wanted to provide an alternative.

Comment: Re-did the spell and tried it your way, gives me <Binary data> in the col

Comment: I think you need to make your column `timestamp` for this to work not `datetime`.

Comment: $current_timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO table-name(col-name) values ('{current_timestamp'})";

With TIMESTAMP..gives me <Binary data>

Comment: What is the length of the field. You may need to expand it.

Comment: Yes, you need to make it big enough to fit all those characters, so 20 would be better.